# How can I extract the variables used in a Sympy polynomial into a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Here's the code:

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.abc import *
   
a1 = sym.Poly(3*x + 4*y + 9*z + a + b + c)
```

So, here in the above equation I have used the variables x, y, z, a, b and c.
So, is there a way by which I can extract the variables used in an equation , preferably in a list.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is unclear but maybe `list(eq.free_symbols)` does what you want.

Comment: I'm asking that if there's a way or attribute of the sympy.polynomial class using which I can get a list of the variables appearing in an equation

Answer (score 0):

```
[_ for _ in a1.atoms() if type(_) is sym.Symbol]
```

will list the symbols used in your expression.